# How to load font files from node_module(otf files)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, angular, sass

We are unable to load fonts file from node module. and getting below error.

```
Can't resolve 'assets/fonts/roman.woff2' in 'C:\Projects\GIT2\newbusinessapp\projects\newbusinessapp\src'
```

We are including assets through angular.json file. but still no result.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Publico Light Roman';
src: url('assets/fonts/roman.woff2');
```

}

```
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "node_modules/@mypackage/assets/assets/fonts",
            "output": "/assets/fonts"
          },
```

Please post here if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with ~

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Publico Light Roman';
src: url('~/assets/fonts/roman.woff2'); 
}
```